# Dynamic binding concern

Tags: java, binding, overloading

I've really tried to understand it but I couldn't. Why is it printed: ***Selected: method 1*** two times?
I thought that it should be printed

***Selected: method 1***

***Selected: method 2***

because the real type of c2 is ClassTwo. Please see the code below.

```
public class ClassOne{}

public class ClassTwo extends ClassOne{}

public class Module {
    public void methodModule(ClassOne c){
        System.out.println("Selected: method 1");
    }
    public void methodModule(ClassTwo c) {
        System.out.println("Selected: method 2");
    }
}

public class TestModule {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Module m = new Module();
        ClassOne c1 = new ClassOne();
        ClassOne c2 = new ClassTwo();
        m.methodModule(c1);
        m.methodModule(c2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have method `methodModule` **overloaded** in your class `Module`.

Alough you assigned a ClassTwo object to `c2` by: `ClassOne c2 = new ClassTwo();`, but since `c2` is declared as a reference to `ClassOne` object, the `methodModule(ClassOne c)` method will be selected, when `m.methodModule(c2);` is executed.

See below code for Dynamic binding, which output your expected results:

```
Selected: method 1
Selected: method 2
```

In this code example, **Overriding** is used,which is usually related with Dynamic binding:

```
class ClassOne extends Module{
    @Override
    public void methodModule(){
        System.out.println("Selected: method 1");
    }
}

class ClassTwo extends Module {
    @Override
    public void methodModule() {
        System.out.println("Selected: method 2");
    }
}

class Module {
    public  void methodModule() {
        System.out.println("Selected: module mothod");
    }

}

public class TestModule {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Module c1 = new ClassOne();
        Module c2 = new ClassTwo();
        c1.methodModule();
        c2.methodModule();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not dynamic binding. It's Static binding you can see the example in the link

[See here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html)

In your example at compile It will be clear that which method will get executed. That's why It's Static binding.

Dynamic Binding is What decide at run time.

For Example in the given link if you see =>

at run time it will be known to the program at `start()` method of the `Car` Class will get executed.

Moreover you can also see  Liskov Substitution Principle

> If S and T are objects, and T is a subtype of S, then T may be used
>   where S is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Some Key points are:

- You have overloaded method `methodModule`
- You are inheriting `classOne`

When you inherit, it becomes a subclass so the type will be compatible if you assign subclass to your parent.

If you don't inherit, it might throw some incompatible error.

When you call the method which is overloaded it will look for the same type and executes which prints first method twice.